# Check if index exists with a pandas interval index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I am working with the MS geolife dataset. The dataset has 2 types of files one that contains GPS tracks and another that contains labels with the mode of transit over time windows.

```
'lat', 'long', 'null', 'alt', 'DateTime', 'Date', 'Time'
39.921712,116.472343,0,13,39298.1462037037,2007-08-04,03:30:32
39.921705,116.472343,0,13,39298.1462152778,2007-08-04,03:30:33
39.921695,116.472345,0,13,39298.1462268519,2007-08-04,03:30:34
39.921683,116.472342,0,13,39298.1462384259,2007-08-04,03:30:35
```

```
Start Time  End Time    Transportation Mode
2007/06/26 11:32:29 2007/06/26 11:40:29 bus
2008/03/28 14:52:54 2008/03/28 15:59:59 train
2008/03/28 16:00:00 2008/03/28 22:02:00 train
2008/03/29 01:27:50 2008/03/29 15:59:59 train
```

I am using an interval index to perform the join to get transport type, but the issue is that not all of the data is labeled so sometimes there will not be data in the given ranges. I have looked around but can't seem to find a good way to check if the index will exist so I get a key error.

```
LAggDf['Start Time'] = pd.to_datetime(LAggDf['Start Time'])
LAggDf['End Time'] = pd.to_datetime(LAggDf['End Time'])
LAggDf.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(LAggDf['Start Time'], LAggDf['End Time'], closed='both')

def idk(x):
    try:  # not easy to chech if in an interval index
        return LAggDf.iloc[LAggDf.index.get_loc(x)]['Transportation Mode']
    except:
        pass

TAggDf['TransMode'] = TAggDf['DateTime'].apply(lambda x: idk(x))
```

This is kinda working but obviously not great. Basically, I just want to replace the try-except with an if statement that would check the index.

Comment: You forgot to add the column names to the first dataframe you have in the question.

Comment: Edited, Also I have a line to combine the Date and Time columns into one DateTime Col `df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Date')) + pd.to_timedelta(df.pop('Time'))` so thats the TAggDf['DateTime'] I have